# LabView--- How do I map the range of acceleration values to certain frequency?

Tags: labview

I'm using myRio device's accelerometer. I get 3 acceleration values from the accelerometer x,y and z. How do I map the values of XYZ to a certain frequency? For example if x=1, y=0 and z=0  will equals to 500hz.

[image: XYZ are share variables how to do i equate them to certain frequency]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case provided in screen shot you can move Variables X,Y and Z outside the `case loop`. Then check if`x=1, y=0 and z=0` use `AND` logic operation to check if all X,Y and Z meets your requirements and plug the output from the AND comparison to case selector. Then in true case you can put value of 500 (inside case structure) and in false case use default values if unwired (right click on tunnel).

Other approach (especially when you would like to have different Hz values not only 500 Hz in this particular case) is to change case structure from boolean states (true/false) to several numbers. If X = 1 then input value will be 500 Hz. If X = 2 then input value will be 600 Hz and so on.

Comment: You welcome :) If you have any further questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to map the variables to frequency?

Strictly speaking this is not a Labview question but a question about your model:

```
Frequency = f(X,Y,Z)
```

You have to choose your function f and then translate it into G.

**Example**

Let's suppose Frequency does not depend on X and Y but only on Z.
Moreover for Z=1 Frequency should be 500Hz and depends on Z linearly for Z between 0 and 1.

So here's our mapping:

```
Frequency = Z * 500 (0<=Z<=1)
```

And here's our Labview implementation:

[image]